# How to synchronize multiple Office 365 tenant apps to a custom MVC application app using Azure AD sigle sign-on

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have read through lots of articles on Office 365 and Azure AD, but I am confused. This is my issue: There are several schools with individual Office 365 subscriptions (multi-tenant) and their users (teachers and students) sign into an MVC application (standalone app) to access their mails, calendar and other school related features.

I have to create single sign on for all these users from their Office 365 accounts using Azure AD and synchronize Office 365 mailbox, calendar and other apps with this application.

What path do I need to take to establish single sign on (ADFS or password only or something else with AD Connect) and can this be done with single Azure AD tenant? And also how to synchronize Office apps?

Comment: Is this a hypothetical situation, such as a homework?

Comment: no, this is a real life problem, why? i currently need a solution asap

Comment: A couple of reasons: firstly it sounds like you've not done anything yet to try to resolve it, and readers here tend to ask for prior effort first. Also, on Stack Overflow I sometimes see people given huge responsibility by their employers that they are not yet ready to handle. Looking after that number of users is a big responsibility - do you have colleagues who can set you in the right direction in the first instance?

Comment: Note also that volunteers here do not respond well to "urgent" or "ASAP" requests - please refrain from adding that sort of thing, if only to avoid downvotes. We understand that you have deadlines, but it is not urgent for anyone else, and readers won't be hurried into action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different questions here. I don't know what is meant by "how to synchronize Office apps".

Creating an app that can be signed on to by users in different tenants can be done. Look for "[asp.net mvc azure ad multitenant](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/)":

1. Register the application in one Azure AD
2. Make it multitenant by flipping the switch in the application configuration in the Azure management portal
3. Publish the application and verify that you can sign in with a user located in the "home AAD" (where the application is published)
4. Test sign-on with a user in a different AAD. That may involve first signing on as an admin user to grant the application access to that AAD tenant.

Comment: Thank you very much, I also wanted to understand how to achieve authentication and as per my understanding now ADAL takes care of it: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of domains that can be added to an AAD?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain more about your questions . From your description , it seems you want to build a multi-tenant .Net MVC web application as @RasmusW suggested .And in addition , if you want to get O365 mails,calendars information in your web app , you could use [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs) , also click [here](https://github.com/search?q=aspnet%20sample%20user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories) for code samples .

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This takes care of my issue for integration. I am unable to pick two answers as correct as I had multiple questions.